# how to set cross domain session

Tags: ajax, session, authentication, cross-domain

i'm trying to create a web app with back and front end separated, so there is two project here. The reason is there is a plan in the future to create mobile version as well, so i made it decoupled.
Just FYI the back are created with PHP using laravel4 and barryvdh CORS
and the front end are created purely with angularjs and bootstrap.
The current situation is that i create a rest API in my back end app to do login, auth, and logout.
and in the front end i have 2 pages, which is login and index page.

Login page are composed of username, password input field and submit button,
when user click submit button, it will call the login rest API from the back end and i expect it would persist cookie to the front end page if login success, but it doesn't (because of cross origin policy, i've research as much).

The question is, is there any way to set sessions across domains now it is 2014, where any article i found are from 2012 older. If it's not possible, what's the easiest way to persist session across domain besides OAUTH2 and openID (because their learning curve are just too steep, the application i'm creating are just small app)

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I have done so far to work with cross-domain sessions is to create a "passport" service on a another domain and validate & handle the session from the there.

For example...

domain1.com has webserver1
domain2.com has webserver2
passport.com has webserver3

Whenever I connect either to domain1.com or domain2.com I'm including a line at the very top of the script index checking on passport.com/check.php whether there's a browser session already initialized under the name of "PASSPORT", if so, I finish the checking on passport.com and let the script on domain1.com or domain2.com to do their stuff.

In case the browser session wasn't initialized, the check.php will redirect the index via header() to the login.php page. This will validate against LDAP and if binding the user is OK then the browser session is initialized with the name of "PASSPORT" and including all the fields I need furthermore to validate the user and its accesses. Ref back to the index once is done.

When the user goes from domain1.com to domain2.com (or the other way around) the script included at the top of each index will check the session again all the time, taking the user to the login script or letting him access the required site.

As additional checking you can create the session and add variables such as "valid until", "access level", etc.

Hope this helps and if you need further clarification let me know.

Best,
Emiliano.